# getScaledFrameAtTime from MediaMetadataRetriever is too slow to return bitmap in Android 10

Tags: android, android-10.0, mediametadataretriever

Getting bitmap from video using metadata retriever  takes too much of time in Android 10 but below Android 10 works well. Facing this issue only in Android 10.
 `getFrameAtTime` and `getScaledFrameAtTime` both are slow in Android 10.

**Here I have added the code that I used to get bitmap form video**

```
  Bitmap bitmap = null;
    MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(context, videoUri);
    bitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever.getScaledFrameAtTime( ONE_SECOND_IN_MILLI, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC,THUMB_WIDTH,THUMB_HEIGHT);
```

**build gradle sdk version**

```
   compileSdkVersion = 28
   def nativeBuildSystem = 'none'
     defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.example"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Hi, did you get an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

bug of Android P , like huawei P30, newest has fixed. Uri convert to file is a valid method

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a source for this, so OP can get more information on the issue.